# EF Core migration section does not available in publish wizard

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, database-migration, entity-framework-core, webdeploy

Web deploy publish wizard so not shows EF database contexts for migration.

[image]
I do not able to apply latest version migrate while publishing to staging database.

How to enable that?

Comment: did you use that kind of `db migration` with earlier version ?

Comment: Yes, Earlier it was coming in the wizard, but i don't no why it get hide.